# How can I remove symlinks within a folder and its subfolder?

Tags: files, symlink

I have a folder which contains symlinks. These symlinks causes problem with my encfs setup. I want to remove all symlinks from this folder and its subfolder. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `find`:

```
 find path/to/your/folder -maxdepth 2 -type l -delete
```

`-type l` finds symbolic links only, see `man find`. To define how deep find should go in the directroy tree, use the `-maxdepth` option.